# Simple description of a Grothendieck topology on the opposite of f.p. complex algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, topos-theory

Let ${\cal A}$ be the category of finitely presented $\mathbb{C}$-algebras.
Let $J$ be the largest subcanonical Grothendieck topology on ${{\cal A}^{op}}$ such that the local algebras in $\cal A$ are cocovered only by the maximal sieve.
Is there a more explicit description of $J$? (Something analogous to the usual description of the Zariski topology in terms of a finitary basis.)
Note: it contains the Zariski topology.